# What is a nice way to convince Mathematica to use $\tau$ instead of $\pi$ in evaluated formulas?

Tags: pattern-matching, customization, semantic-matching

I have tried like

```
Replace[something, {2*π -> HoldForm[τ]}]
```

Although it works well where a lone `2 π` symbol, it fails to simplify e.g. `4 π^2`  ( probably because of how the multiply operation works)

e.g. this fails:

```
Evaluate[4*π ] /. {2*π -> HoldForm[τ]}
```

Anyone has found a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of

```
  4*π /. 2*π -> τ
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do

```
 4*π /. π -> τ/2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Look at your replacement:

```
4*\[Pi] /. 2*\[Pi] -> tau
```

Replacement works strictly with pattern, no AI involved. Therefore "2 Pi" does not match "4 Pi". The calculation has to be done separately. E.g.:

```
i /2 /. Pi -> tau
(* 2 tau *)
```